# Arithmetic operations between SQL select results

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I need to do something like this as a part of a bigger script:

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('(SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnA = "'  ,ColumnA, ' "THEN 1 ELSE 0 end))/(select total 
   from hd_totals where ColumnA = "'  ,ColumnA, ' ") AS "'  ,ColumnA, ' "')) 
FROM table inner join.....
```

The problem is that I can't do the / operation because it gives an error, even if the select output is a single value.
I don't even know how to use aliases or to store in a variable because it's a rather complex (to me) environment I'm creating here...

Comment: You can't use string manipulation *(such as `CONCAT`)* to create a new SQL expression and then have it execute, all inside the same SQL statement.  Could you show us some sample data, describe the rules you want to apply to that data, and show the results that you expect?  *(Google MCVE for more details of framing questions in this manner.)*

Comment: It may be possible to directly query for the results you need instead of generating queries via a query.  Please show the structure and some sample data from the relevant tables, and explain the result you require.  Example output will help too.

Comment: The problem is that everything works well if you delete the part with the /, that is my point. The thing is similar to (select ....)/(select ...) even if the 2 select results are single integer numbers i can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this : use CAST to have DECIMAL type, and use coalesce to prevent null values?

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('COALESCE(CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnA = "'  ,ColumnA, ' "THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)) AS DECIMAL(10,4)),0)/COALESCE(CAST((select total 
   from hd_totals where ColumnA = "'  ,ColumnA, ' ") AS DECIMAL(10,4)),0.01) AS "'  ,ColumnA, ' "')) 
FROM table inner join.....
```

Note : there is an arbitrary constant 0.01 to prevent dividing by 0.

More important note : If I was you I would also add a CASE WHEN to check that you don't divide by 0.